# Picklist return lookup as dependent

Tags: lookup, picklist, dependent-picklist, case-object

I have a request in the case object with fields:

- Requestor: `Lookup user`
- Are you the user affected?   `Picklist (yes/no)`

Then if the answer is **YES** = a field called User affected is filled with the requestor name

if choose **NO** = a lookup field for user is enabled to then insert the affected one.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot achieve it using standard layout/dependent picklist. But you can create a custom visualforce page and achieve it. Then you will have to override New/Edit page in case with this visualforce page.

Comment: Actually, i forgot to mention that one of the requirements is not to user visualforce page. Btw, thanks victor

Comment: Without visualforce page, you will not be able to enable and disable lookup field. But you can write a validation rule to ensure that whenever that lookup field value is "Yes", user should select some value in lookup

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this.

1)Create a check box.

2)if it is checked populate the User affected field with user in the Requestor: Lookup user with a trigger (may be workflow since it is a lookup u may need to write trigger for it).
3)write a filter on the filter Lookup to show the users only when a checkbox is not checked.
If you have any doubts please post comment I will respond.